# Returned Parameters in PHP PDO MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, linux, pdo, parameters

### The Problem

Since moving my web application from a Windows Server to a Linux Server, I have encountered all sorts of issues with my SQL Wrapper Class, I hope that this is the last one...

I had been using the SQLSRV PDO Driver for Windows, but am now using dblib which I think uses ODBC, it is all quite confusing...

On the previous server, I was able to retrieve OUTPUT parameters from stored procedures extremely easily using the PDO `bindParam()` method.

However, this method does not seem to return my output parameters any more... Has anyone else experienced it?

It is quite hard for me to show some test code as my Wrapper Class builds the queries and parameters dynamically, but I assume it is something like this:

```
$this->query->bindParam(':some_param','some_value',PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT,$value['length']);
```

A few things to note:

1. The Stored Procedures are on the same server, and have not changed, thus I know they are still returning the OUTPUT parameters in the same way.
2. The PHP PDO code has not changed, the only variable here is the PDO driver being used.

### My Question(s)

1. Has anyone experienced this issue with PHP, MSSQL and PDO from a Linux Server?
2. Are there any other methods using PDO or not, to connect to an MSSQL Database from Linux?
3. I am currently using PHP 5.5.18, is there a later version that might fix this? If so, what version and is it stable on CentOS 6?

Comment: Hi @Ben I think you can use odbc + php as an alternative to access the db from linux, you will need freetds driver as well.In addition you can also try `mssql` instead of `sqlsrv` for PDO. as for the output params  I personally never use bindParam to get them, I just fetch them like a `SELECT` statement

Comment: @meda I am using the `mssql` method I think, or whatever one is used by dblib... I would love to return the parameters from the statement, but unfortunately, my job is to bring this software from the desktop to the web, and in doing that, I must keep the database the same, hence why I am using mssql not mysql... :-(

Comment: @meda Can you give me an example of an ODBC connection string? I don't want to have to define each database in an odbc config file, as each client has their own database... Is it possible to do something like: `odbc:DRIVER=FreeTDS;HOSTNAME=10.0.59.160;PORT=1433;DATABASE=Exporter_Profiles;`?

Comment: Connection example for native odbc or pdo/odbc ? are you allowed to change the php code

Comment: @meda I wrote the PHP code :-D!! for PDO ODB if possible... I dont want to define DSN's, I want to be able to dynamically create each PDO connection... The one above gave me the error: `Data source name not found, and no default driver specified` :-(

Comment: have you installed both unixodbc and freetds

Comment: @meda Yes, I believe they are installed. What is the command to check whether they are installed

Comment: `isql –v SERVERNAME USERNAME PASSWORD` for ODBC and `tsql –S SERVERNAME –U USERNAME` for freetds driver

Comment: @meda I don't understand, what do I put into `$connection_string` in `new PDO($connection_string,$username,$password)`? Surely the above wont work?

Comment: It's like any connection it could be long so if you dont want DSN here is an example ,`PDO("odbc:Server=dbServerIpAddress,portnumber;Database=database", "username", 'password');`

Comment: @meda It says Data source name not found, and no default driver specified. Where do I define the default driver and what driver to I use?

Comment: did you try the test command I gave you ? look in `/etc/odbc.ini` thats where you point to freetds driver